# Execute function on bottom of the page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to execute the function `"nextResults()"` if the user has scroll on bottom, using javascript or jquery.
My code doesnt work.

My code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() = $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
          nextResults();
     }
});
```

Comment: "if the user has scroll on bottom"? What does that mean? Could you kindly show some HTML?

Comment: Yes, i scroll on bottom of the page, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
$(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
          nextResults();
     }
});
```

wrong conditional expression, it should be '==' but yours is '='

you can test it here, check the browser developer tools console: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ap31porw/)

Comment: hmm, I am not sure what are css or js you are using, but the solution I gave you is an standard one.

Comment: can i use a alternative? Example: If the user scrolls over a div or anchor?